# how to load local json file in single page application with angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, single-page-application

I'm building a what called mini single page application which all the logic is in the client side and i'm using Angular for that.
my problem is to load a JSON file which is not stored at any server but in my project tree - each time that i'm trying to load the file i'm getting 404.3 error code (tried with several browsers) - there is no issue with my call as i tried to call to a JSON file that stored on webserver and it worked wonderful  - the only problem is when i'm trying to call to a local JSON.
this is my call:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('/Data/names.json')
.success(function (data, status, header, config) {
    console.log("file loaded");
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(header);
    console.log(config);

})
.error(function (data, status, header, config) { 
    console.log("ERROR file didn't load");
    //console.log(data);
    //console.log(status);
    //console.log(header);
    //console.log(config);
 })
```

});

**solved**
by adding web.config file to my project with the following lines:

`<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>`

Comment: Is your SPA being run like file://index.html? or is it on a webserver when you're testing with the json file?

Comment: its not on a webserver, its running  like http://localhost:5497

Comment: How does your function get "$http"? You can try injecting "$http" to the controller function? Like app.controller("myCtrl", ["$http", function(...){}]);

Comment: ok so i solved my issue by adding web.config file with the following lines:<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding web.config file to my project with the following lines:

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```